# Tones play through PC speaker when Blue Screen of Death (BSOD) appears?

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I've been getting a BSOD with error code 1E recently (related to a 3rd party driver).  However, the really weird thing is that when the blue screen comes up, the computer plays an odd series of "tones" out the speaker.  The series of tones is like a rising scale, about half second per tone, and a total of 7 or 8 frequencies, then it repeats.  It does this over and over until you power off (I have it set not to reboot automatically).

Has anyone encountered the musical notes before?  Does it mean something specific?

**Edit**

It's an HP Compaq 6200 Pro, with motherboard part # 615114-001.  BIOS is J01 v02.21.

Comment: What make and model motherboard? What BIOS + revision?

Comment: @BigChris - I updated the question with that info.

Comment: Sounds like broken sound card driver. :)

Comment: @SencerH. - there are no speakers attached (just PC speaker) and only the sound-card built into the motherboard.

Comment: Some of the well-known brands products has integration between internal speaker and sound card. If you sure you can't play mp3 audio while no external speakers attached to computer than you have to change `speaker` to `buzzer` or `beeper`. `speaker`, makes me confused because that thing's name is not speaker :).

Comment: @SencerH. - oh, I've always heard it called a [PC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_speaker) [Speaker](http://wiki.osdev.org/PC_Speaker).

Comment: Misslead of the tech service persons :) they named often pc speaker instead buzzer. Many people can't imagine what is the buzzer.  Thats why they say pc speaker to make people understand.